# SQL Server Polybase and Oracle Exadata HA/DR connection strings

Tags: sql-server, etl, polybase

Working with SQL Server 2019 Enterprise CU18 Polybase (On-premise). I have a working connection from SQL Server to Oracle that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [OracleDataSource] 
WITH (LOCATION = 'oracle://ExaData1:1521', CREDENTIAL = [OracleCredential])
```

However, we have an HA/DR pair for our exadata system. ExaData1 and ExaData2.  If we did this in a linked server, the connetion would look like this:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=YES)(FAILOVER=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ExaData1.domain.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ExaData2.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OracleTNSName)))
```

Yet, I can't seems to define it this way in Polybase (at least I haven't figure out how to yet).  I need to figure out how to list both possible servers in the External Data Source so when the DB fails over, it will follow it naturally.

The other option is to figure out how to use the TNS Name, rather than the server name for the Location, but I've not figured that out either. Currently, when I define a table, it looks like this, which is based upon the previously defined data source, listing the TNS name as part of the DATA_SOURCE properties:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Polybase].[sample]
(
    [SID] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [MESSAGE_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [MESSAGE_ID] [nvarchar](3) NULL
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [OracleDataSource],LOCATION = N'[OracleTNSNAME.domain.com].OracleSchema.SAMPLE')
```

Anyone have suggestions or options as I'm not finding anything in the MS documenation.

Appreciate any and all support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
oracle//server1:1521; AlternateServers=(server2:1521,server3:1521,server4:1521); LoadBalancing=true
```

Comment: This does not appear to work.  If I follow the test recommendation above for the LOCATION parameter, I get the following error:

`Msg 105001, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
External access operation failed because the location URI is invalid. Revise the URI and try again.`

If I move  
`AlternateServers=(server2:1521,server3:1521,server4:1521); LoadBalancing=true`  
to the CONNECTION_OPTIONS section, it creates the data source, but won't connect to the DB.

Comment: You're right, this seems to be only available in Progress DataDirect ODBC driver, as it seems you won't be able to do it using the standard driver shipped with SQL Server neither ODP.Net, see more information here: https://docs.progress.com/en-US/bundle/datadirect-oracle-jdbc-60/page/AlternateServers.html

Answer (score 0):

The only other option to connect is by using ExaData SCAN name (configured by Oracle database administrator, which resolves to any of the nodes using a single name). From Oracle it looks like this:

```
(DESCRIPTION =
      (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=90) (RETRY_COUNT=20)(RETRY_DELAY=3) (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)
                 ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=sales-scan.mycluster.example.com)(PORT=1521))
                           (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oltp.example.com)))
```

Then from SQL Server you connect to sales-scan.mycluster.example.com

Comment: We use a similar convention for the linked servers.  It looks like this:  `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=exadata1-scan1.crlcorp.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=exadata2-scan1.crlcorp.com)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=OracleTNSName.crlcorp.com)))` where we list out both scans.  But it still requires both scans to be HA/DR

Comment: I don't think this is the way to specify it, there should be a DNS which resolves to multiple different IP's, see from the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rilin/about-connecting-to-an-oracle-rac-database-using-scans.html

Comment: in talking with the Oracle DBA, you are both correct and lack understanding (or at least I did).  In our case ExaData1-scan1 is for a 2 node exadata cluster in Data Center a, whereas ExaData2-scan1 is in for Data Center 2.  A different technology is required to put a single name in front of these two systems, which we don't currently use.  Hence why we have the 2 scan names in the connection string.